# Can Hamel bases be treated as a subset of the Shauder bases?

Tags: functional-analysis

I am not sure I've understood well the difference between Hamel & Schauder bases.

According to Wikipedia,

> a Schauder basis or countable basis is similar to the usual (Hamel)
> basis of a vector space; the difference is that Hamel bases use linear
> combinations that are finite sums, while for Schauder bases they *may
> be* infinite sums.

So, a Schauder base may use combinations of finite sums, or infinite sums. A Hamel basis may only use combinations of finite sums. If we accept this statement, it follows that the Hamel bases can be regarded as a subset of the Schauder bases. I.e., every Schauder basis that uses combinations of finite sums, is a Hamel basis too.

But several definitions of the Schauder basis across the internet seem to include extra conditions, like a uniqueness in the representation of the sum  of the elements for every x ∈ X. These are not implied on the definitions of a Hamel base.

Could it be that wikipedia simplifies the difference? Or is every Hamel basis a Schauder one too?

Comment: A Shauder basis of $X$ which is also a Hamel basis of $X$ exists only when $X$ is finite dimensional.  Of course any Shauder basis of a Banach space $X$ is linearly independent and thus it is also a Hamel basis for some set $\subset X$.

Comment: You've got it backwards. Every Schauder basis will be a subset of a Hamel basis (assuming the Axiom of Choice, anyway). A Hamel basis can only be a subset of a Schauder basis when they coincide, which is the finite dimensional case.

Comment: "Every Schauder basis that is a finite sum, is a Hamel basis too". This doesn't make sense. A Schauder basis is a collection of vectors. It is not a sum, finite or infinite.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I edited it

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I think he means that a Hamel basis is necessarily a Schauder basis, since if every vector can be written as a finite sum of the elements, then every vector can certainly be written as an infinite sum of elements. This is ignoring any requirement for the Schauder basis that the sum be unqiue.

Comment: But a Schauder basis that uses combinations of infinite sums is by definition not a Hamel basis. At least according to that wiki-page

Comment: @eyeballfrog Exactly. It seems that the wikipedia article is not 100% accurate.

Comment: Well, the issue is that uniqueness of the sum *is* part of the definition of a Schauder basis. For an infinite dimensional vector space, a Schauder basis can't be a Hamel basis (because some of the vectors in the space require infinite sums) and a Hamel basis can't be a Schauder basis (because there are distinct infinite sums that add up to the same vector).

Comment: No, the definition is accurate. When you can talk about Schauder bases (which requires a notion of convergence), in the infinite dimensional case there will be elements of the Hamel basis that can be written as infinite linear combinations of other vectors in the basis, so that what you have is not a Schauder basis.

Comment: @GEdgar I disagree with your first sentence. In the space of finitely supported sequences equipped with the supremum norm, the canonical vectors $(e_n)_n$ are both a Schauder basis and a Hamel basis; the only thing is that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \alpha_n e_n$ does not converge if the sequence $(\alpha_n)_n$ is not itself finitely supported.

Comment: @mechanodroid It holds over complete spaces.

Comment: @Arturo True, if $(b_n)_n$ is a Schauder basis for a Banach space $X$, then the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{2^n} \frac{b_n}{\|b_n\|}$ converges absolutely, and hence converges to a vector in $X$ which is not a finite linear combination of $b_n$ as this would contradict the uniqueness of representation.